# ¿Como configurar apache con diversos virtualhost (nginx como proxy server)?

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

Buenas , tengo instalado en local un entorno con ubuntu con apache para usar apache como proxy reverse de NGINX.

La idea es servir las peticiones de nginx por el puerto 80 y ejecutar apache en el puerto 8080 ,hasta  aquí me funciona.

Mi estructura donde dispongo los archivos es en /var/www/html

Ahora lo que intento hacer es un virtualhost que al poner "localhost" me coja por defecto la raiz, es decir, el directorio "/var/www/html" y un virtualhost que al poner "www.test.io" me vaya al directorio "/var/www/html/portal" , para ello dispongo de estos ficheros de configuración:

**Fichero "test.io.conf" en /etc/apache2/sites-available**

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/portal
ServerName test.io
ServerAlias www.test.io

<Directory /var/www/html/portal>
   AllowOverride All
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

**Fichero "000-default.conf" en /etc/apache2/sites-available**

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Si con un navegador voy a http://localhost:8080 veo que voy a la raiz donde tengo los documentos "/var/www/html/" , pero si en el navegador escribo la URL http://test.io o bien http://www.test.io lo que me hace el navegador es ir realmente a dicho dominio que existe en internet y no al virtualhost que yo he creado.

Gracias.

Comment: Has mirado que no sea por la configuración de DNS que tengas en tu equipo?

Comment: Tenias razón , tuve que modificar el archivo /etc/hosts y todo correcto. Gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entra al terminal (consola) e ingresa:

> sudo nano /etc/hosts

Dentro del archivo de configuración agrega el siguiente parametro:

> 127.0.0.1       www.test.io

Para que el dominio apunte la dirección IP local y así poder acceder al servidor.

Comment: Eso es si está accediento desde Linux. Si lo hace desde Windows tendrá que modificar el archivo hosts C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Comment: Gracias  ,era con linux

Answer (score 2):

Tiene pinta que los ficheros hosts son correctos,  no has puesto nada sobre si has habilitado los ficheros de VirtualHost pero si no es así debes hacerlo:

```
sudo a2ensite test.io.conf
```

Después de aplicar cambios reinicia el servicio de apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda.